# Laplace transforms of non-exponential, non-sinusoidal functions

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

I have gathered my understanding of Laplace transforms from my Diff EQ course and the following YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2y7n6jw5d0

From what I understand, the "peaks" in the Laplace transform represent the way the original function can be formed by combining exponential and sinusoidal functions.

Then it makes perfect sense to me why functions of the form $x^n$ have a single peak at $0$ (the video also mentions functions with a peak at $0$ have infinite integrals, which makes sense.)

My confusion is to how the Laplace transforms of $x^0$, $x^1$, $x^2$... differ. I ran this in MatLab but it was hard to tell what the difference between these functions were.

I understand what the Laplace transforms themselves are ($n!/s^n$) and why they are those values, but I do not understand how the Laplace transform represents these functions when they seem to be very similar functions. That is my main point of confusion.

Comment: It is not quite true that the peaks represent "the way the function can be formed" - the Laplace domain does not really represent a function basis in the strict sense, since its functions are not orthogonal (as they are in a discrete Fourier space, or as they sort-of are in a continuous Fourier space).  Look closely at the form of the inverse Laplace transform - in a way, we do recover the original function by "adding up" stuff from the Laplace space, but that "adding up" is complex contour integration and only takes place along a single path in Laplace space.

Comment: So, we can't quite think of poles in Laplace space exactly the same way we think of delta functions in Fourier space - the analogy is useful but imperfect.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No problem!  If that was sufficient to answer your question, I'll try to get around to writing it up properly as an answer instead of a comment.